# Query about why there is a torque on this spinning ring in a magnetic field

Tags: classical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, gyroscopes

[image: ![enter image description here]

We learnt in class that the $\vec m\times \vec B$ is the torque of a current loop in a magnetic field. I was trying to understand this by considering the diagram above. Let the B field be pointing in the positive y direction and the positive x direction be pointing to the right orthogonal to it. At point P, the velocity of the charges has a component x direction. As $F=qv\times B$ The force must be orthogonal to the x and y directions. This means it is either pointing into or out of the ring. The y component of the charges velocity at P is parallel to the magnetic field and so has no effect on the overall lorentz force at that point.

Consider the point where I have draw the electron, it is travelling out of the page so to speak. Thus its lorentz force will be orthoognal to the  z (out of page) and y directions. Thus it must be along the x direction. This is a translational force and will not provide a torque.

Why is there a net torque on this system?

Comment: Attach a co-ordinate system next to your picture to be clearer.

Comment: I have used a different diagram, does that help?